# Can I generate a custom notification? [solved]

Tags: release-loki, notifications, script

Is there a way to generate a custom notification, and how?

I have a bash script that performs rsync backups, and this script runs as a cronjob. I want to have that script generate a notification to tell me that the backup has completed, with something like the time and date the job successfully finished. I could do this in other distros. Can I do this in EOS?

I've searched the elementaryos.stackexchange.com quite thoroughly, and have also googled it, but cannot find an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer that works for me. I can use the command

```
notify-send
```

More info at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Comment: This works just fine when run on terminal. But if you try to run it as a Cron task it doesn't work (at least in my setup: elementary OS 5.1.7). There are several solutions for this in AskUbuntu forum : https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab?newreg=c86b39d8f0bf4097a454dce1c38826ba